# snowpark procedure timeout 3600s

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I have a snowpark procedure that timeouts once it exceeds 3600s, knowing that in the user/session/warehouse parameters, the parameter "STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS" is set by default to 172800.

Comment: Hi, check the CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE , if it is False, change it to True as True will keep it alive with out any time limit.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. I was facing a timeout on my python worksheet. So I opened a ticket with snowflake. The representative said that he has increased the time limit for my user. Based on this my guess is that this time limit might only be configurable from the backend. So and you need snowflake's support to increase it.